# how to convert dataframe of booleans to dataframe of 1 and np.NaN?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe filled with True and False values, and I'd like to get a dataframe from it with the True replaced with 1 and the False replaced with np.NaN. I've tried using dataframe.replace, but it gave a dataframe filled with all True. Is there a way to do it without using for loops and if's?

Example, this is the dataframe I have, with T for True and F for False (not strings 'T' and 'F'; sorry, could not figure out how to format a nicely spaced table in the wiki):

2008-01-02 16:00:00  T T F
2008-01-03 16:00:00  T T T
2008-01-04 16:00:00  T T F
2008-01-07 16:00:00  T T T
2008-01-08 16:00:00  T T F

This is what I would like to change it to:

2008-01-02 16:00:00  1 1 np.NaN
2008-01-03 16:00:00  1 1 1
2008-01-04 16:00:00  1 1 np.NaN
2008-01-07 16:00:00  1 1 1
2008-01-08 16:00:00  1 1 np.NaN

These are the lines I tried to replace the True and False, and got a dataframe filled with all True values:

```
df.replace(to_replace=True, value=1, inplace=True, method=None)   
df.replace(to_replace=False, value=np.NAN, inplace=True, method=None)
```

When tried separately, the first line alone does not change anything; the second line converts all the values to True.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`applymap()` can be used to apply a function to every element of a `dataframe`

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame([[True, True, False],[False, False, True]]).T

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
       0      1
0   True  False
1   True  False
2  False   True

In [3]: df.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x else np.nan)
Out[3]:
    0   1
0   1 NaN
1   1 NaN
2 NaN   1
```

You can also use a `dict`:

```
In [4]: d = {True:1, False:np.nan}

In [5]: df.applymap(lambda x: d[x])
Out[5]:
    0   1
0   1 NaN
1   1 NaN
2 NaN   1
```

Addressing DSM's comment from below.  I misread the OP and assumed the datetime was an index.  If it's not an index this worked for me:

```
In [6]: df.applymap(lambda x: d.get(x,x))
Out[6]:
    0   1                    2
0   1 NaN  2012-01-01 00:00:00
1 NaN   1  2012-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: This will break if the first column is made up of `datetime` instances.  Something like `df.applymap(lambda x: d.get(x,x))` should bypass that.  [I'm kind of annoyed at myself I can't find a nice way to do this, but my first two approaches work with `"T"` and `"F"` but fail with `True` and `False`.]

Comment: I ammended my response to work with dataframes with heterogenous data.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm somewhat new to python and appreciate the refinements and pointers.  I will amend my response again.

Comment: Hmm.  That doesn't seem to be working -- look at the output again.  It seems to be because the type of the objects in the `DataFrame` is actually `numpy.bool_`, not Python's `bool`.

Comment: `df = df.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x else np.NAN)`  ---- achieved the desired result. Thank you for your help. I had the same issue with not working with the True and False, but I think applymap returns a new dataframe after applying the function. I have seen some other dataframe methods (eg sort) have a parameter 'inplace', which changes the original dataframe, but applymap does not, looks like it returns a new dataframe, so I have to add the include the explicit equals sign: "df = df.applymap...". Also, the date column is the index. Thank you again both for your help.

Answer (score 2):

try this. `where` works because the first use by default `nan`s out the not-found entries (e.g. anything that is not == 'T'), then 2nd replaces the non-found entries with the 1

```
In [48]: df = pd.DataFrame([ 'T', 'T', 'T', 'F', 'F' ], columns=['value'],index=pd.date_range('20010101',periods=5))

In [49]: df
Out[49]: 
           value
2001-01-01     T
2001-01-02     T
2001-01-03     T
2001-01-04     F
2001-01-05     F

In [50]: df.where(df=='T').where(df!='T',1)
Out[50]: 
           value
2001-01-01     1
2001-01-02     1
2001-01-03     1
2001-01-04   NaN
2001-01-05   NaN
```